# Move an input text with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to manipulate a text from an input box.
First, i want to move it up and then to disappear.

Here's how it disappears:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //a bit stupid loop
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        //text disappearance
        var input = $("#textboxid");

        input.delay(5000).animate({

        }, 4000, function () {

            $(this).val('').css('color', 'black');
        }); 
    }
});
```

So how to move it up, before the "disappearance"?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a mess. Use this one:

This executes when user clicks on the text box.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#textboxid").click(function(){
        $(this).animate("margin-top","-50px",1000,function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
});
```

You can use a little trick. Wrap the text box into a div or something like that. And remove every style from the text box. Then. When the text box moves it seems like the text moved. Before that you should set the `overflow` of the container to `hidden` and give it a width and height.

Comment: With code you proposed, the input box disappears, while i want only the text to disappear.

Comment: You mean. The text disappears from the text box? Ok I will edit my answer